# Analytic Method for Solving $8n^2 > 64n\log_2{n}$

Tags: inequality, alternative-proof

I was reading a book which gave the running time of an algorithm $A$ to be $8n^2$ and another algorithm $B$ to be $64n\log_2{n}$ and asked what is the greatest input size $n$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A$ is faster than $B$ (It is earlier established that $B$ is faster for all values past a certain point $c$, finding that $c$ is the question.)

The problem can be mathematically formulated as solving the following inequality:

$$\tag{1}\quad 8n^2 < 64n\log_2{n}.$$

I did this easily enough by writing a quick program in C (The answer is for all input sizes less than 44), but I was displeased with that method; it just felt dirty, ya know? I'm looking for an analytic solution, should one exist. I've done the following work.

$$8n^2 < 64n\log_2{n}\implies n < 8\log_2{n}\implies n < \log_2{n^8}\implies 2^{n} < n^8.$$

Anyone know how to analytically derive the result of $n<44?$

Comment: I think these finite things are inherently dirty. I don't view anything that can be checked by a computer (in finite time) as clean

Comment: @mathworker21 maybe clean was the wrong word to use, but I wonder if someone could work it out with pure reason rather than just testing cases with a computer like I did.

Comment: well, i don't know how $44$ is supposed to come out of pure reason. you're going to have to do some computation at some point. so why not just have a computer to all the computation. it's arbitrary...

Comment: You're really looking for where they are equal, right?  So $n=log_2n^8$.  Try raisng e to both sides, so $e^n=n^8$?

Comment: Notice $$8n^2 = 64n\log_2(n)\iff  e^{\frac{\log 2}{8} n} = n
\iff -\frac{\log 2}{8} = -\frac{\log 2}{8} n e^{-\frac{\log 2}{8} n}$$
The root for above equation can be expressed in terms of suitable choosen branch of [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) 
$$n = -\frac{8}{\log 2} W\left(-\frac{\log 2}{8}\right)$$
The relevant branch seems to be the branch '-1', If one throw the command
`-8/Log[2]*LambertW[-1,-Log[2]/8]` to WA, one get something reasonable $\approx 43.55926$.

Comment: @achillehui neat, I'm not familiar with this Lambert W function, but thanks.